# Why does Azure Application Gateway logs originalHost_s format like "~^api\\.example\\.com$"

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

In the logs of my new Azure Application Gateway I notice a significant amount of entries that have a value of `~^api\\.example\\.com$` for the `originalHost_s` field, with no value for any of the `requestUri_s, ruleName_s, listenerName_s, backendPoolName_s, backendSettingName_s` fields. So I wonder what these requests are?

I have set up the Azure Application Gateway with several listeners (like for `www.example.com`, `api.example.com`, even `*.example.com`) and those are working as expected, and I see good traffic in the logs for those.

Comment: What value do you see in `Category`?  i.e. I'd expect those fields to be populated where `Category =~ "ApplicationGatewayAccessLog"` but the records missing that info may be from elsewhere; e.g. if you have a firewall enabled those logs could be showing that something's been blocked (i.e. `Category  =~ 'ApplicationGatewayFirewallLog'`), so may not have populated those fields as they're not relevant to that type of log.